# FBNativeAd not loading App Store redirections

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-audience-network

TL;DR
With FBNativeAds, when tapping an action button that goes to the App Store, everything explodes.

I'm integrating FBNativeAds for iOS as indicated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios/native-api). The integration is super simple and everything is working just fine.

BUT, whenever I'm served a "install app" ad, the redirection to the App Store explodes and fills my stack with instructions from the framework.
**Every other action ("learn more", "open app") seem to be working properly**, so I'm assuming all the integration is correctly done. But not one ad going to the App Store works.

[image]

Anybody had any issue like this? I'd be glad to provide code of my integration is needed.

Please, any comment or suggestion might greatly help us. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Andres, did you have any luck solving this issue?

Comment: Hi @marco, to be 100% honest I don't know what happened. There was an issue with the xib being loaded, but we couldn't find it. We ended up deleting everything and doing the integration just like in the example and it worked.

Comment: Hi @andres.cianio thanks for letting me know will try rebuilding the xib file